# Test suite failed to run due to type error (Nest.js)

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I am trying to run an E2E test for one of the controller in my Nest.js app, but the test is failing due to the underlying issue:

```
● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')

      2 | var __decorate = (this && this.__decorate) || function (decorators, target, key, desc) {
      3 |     var c = arguments.length, r = c < 3 ? target : desc === null ? desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, key) : desc, d;
    > 4 |     if (typeof Reflect === "object" && typeof Reflect.decorate === "function") r = Reflect.decorate(decorators, target, key, desc);
        |                                                                                            ^
      5 |     else for (var i = decorators.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) if (d = decorators[i]) r = (c < 3 ? d(r) : c > 3 ? d(target, key, r) : d(target, key)) || r;
      6 |     return c > 3 && r && Object.defineProperty(target, key, r), r;
      7 | };
```

```
# jest-e2e.json

{
  "moduleFileExtensions": ["js", "json", "ts"],
  "rootDir": ".",
  "testEnvironment": "node",
  "testRegex": ".e2e-spec.ts$",
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
  }
}
```

May I know if this issue has been encountered before?

I have tried to freshly install the packages but no luck as of yet.